# Can't get response from local server through wifi

Tags: routing, wireless-networking

I have a local server that hosts several websites. It's turned on into the router and has 192.168.1.2 as the internal IP. If I connect another computer to the same router with a cable, everything works - I can successfully open hosted sites.

But I can't open them through this router's wifi. Ping works, but sites don't open. Internet works, and any external website could be opened.

Also I can open hosted sites from external network. So sites don't work only inside the local network through wifi.

Any hosted site starts working if I update laptop's /etc/hosts with

```
192.168.1.2 mydomain.com
```

There's only one special rule in my router, that sends any inbound traffic to server:

```
internal ip: 192.168.1.2
protocol: TCP
external port: 80
internal port: 80
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to superuser. Can you provide more info on what you mean by ping works, so when on the wifi network you can ping 192.168.1.2? Or does it work when you ping the site name?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on your DNS and DHCP set up. The issue is most probably with your wifi DNS and DHCP set up.

You will need to provide info on how your router and wifi clients are set up to receive DNS and DHCP.

Depending on which web server you are using the website set up and configuration may have something do with it as well.